# Template is not updating, do I need to use $rootScope.$apply or something else?

Tags: javascript, angularjs

I am making a web app that connects to clusters, so 99% of the time, my URLs will be something like: `/cluster/cluster_name/something/else`. Since the routes are dynamic, I need to generate ng-href dynamically in my navigation bar.

Right now, I have a service that parses the URL and pass that to the index template:

```
app.factory('GetCluster',function($location) {
  return {
    cluster: {name: $location.path().split('/')[2]}
  };
});
```

Then in the navigation controller I have this:

```
function NavigationController($scope, $location, GetCluster) {
  $scope.cluster = GetCluster.cluster.name;
  $scope.isActive = function (viewLocation) {
    return viewLocation === $location.path()
  }
```

and finally in the template:

```
<div class="sidebar-nav navbar-collapse" ng-controller="NavigationController">
  <div ng-if="cluster">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/') }" ng-href="/#!/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cluster/' + cluster) }" ng-href="/#!/cluster/{{ cluster }}"><i class="fa fa-sitemap"></i> Cluster</a></li>
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cluster/' + cluster + '/nodes') }" ng-href="/#!/cluster/{{ cluster }}/nodes"><i class="fa fa-hdd-o"></i> Nodes</a></li>
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cluster/' + cluster + '/namespaces') }" ng-href="/#!/cluster/{{ cluster }}/namespaces"><i class="fa fa-database"></i> Namespaces</a></li>
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cluster/' + cluster + '/views') }" ng-href="/#!/cluster/{{ cluster }}/views"><i class="fa fa-search"></i> Views</a></li>
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/cluster/' + cluster + '/tasks') }" ng-href="/#!/cluster/{{ cluster }}/tasks"><i class="fa fa-tasks"></i> Tasks</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
  <div ng-if="!cluster">
    <ul class="nav" id="side-menu">
      <li><a ng-class="{ active: isActive('/')}" ng-href="/#!/"><i class="fa fa-home"></i> Home</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
```

This works, but if I switch to another cluster, the ng-href still point to the old ones. I have to refresh the page in my browser for the right links to appear.

I have tried wrapping the service's return into a `$rootScope.$apply()` but that didn't work. It error'd with something like `$digest already in progress`.

How can I resolve this?

Thank you,

Comment: Angular services are singletons so it will only get used once.  However, you can return a function from the service and call that function in your controller

Answer (score 1):

Try your service like this:

```
app.factory('GetCluster',function($location) {
    return {
        cluster: function() {
            var path = $location.path().split('/');
            return path[2];
        }
    }
});
```

Then call the cluster function in your controller:

```
$scope.cluster = GetCluster.cluster();
```

If you needed to, you could pass the path position as a parameter to return from your service as well.

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it still doesn't update. The navigation bar is outside ng-view, does that change anything?

Comment: No, that shouldn't matter.  Can you provide a fiddle?